# >MPD1=mpd(list,cophenetic(tree)) Error:Error in dis[sppInSample, sppInSample] : subscript out of bound

Tags: r

I am new to R and am encountering an error message that I cannot find a solution.
I am attempting to calculate MPD (mean pairwise distance), without weighting for abundance, with a community species list and a phylogenetic tree in newick format with branch lengths.

I have read in both list and tree .txt files and calculated PD without any problem.
To calculate MPD I have entered:

> MPD1=mpd(list,cophenetic(tree))
> Error:Error in dis[sppInSample, sppInSample] : subscript out of bounds
> Thank you for you help.

Comment: Can you please provide your data or at least a few rows? It is very hard to find a solution without seeing data.

Answer (score 0):

As one comment has already pointed out, it's hard to answer without any dataset being made available. However, I just encountered the same problem and the issue (as the error message suggests) lies with the distance matrix produced by cophenetic(). This stems from the species name order of the community matrix and that of the distance matrix not being matched up. Do that and your code should be executable.